# Trying to import a CSV using custom data, but requires CiviID or External ID in the data

Tags: data-import

I have a CSV of gmail messages including: date, to, from, subject, message. I wish to import it into Civi but it is **missing required field "Civi ID or External ID"** both of which are not tied to the gmail addresses. Is there a work around, or setting I can turn off? Maybe an option to use names or email instead of ID?

Comment: Did you try Civi Import Helper extension that I linked in your last question? That helps with this problem.

Comment: Oh I forgot about that oops. I'll look into it now.

Comment: Are you familiar with Greenleaf hosting? I cant find where to upload extensions.